# I am having issues with the amount when I run the command with while loop in python

Tags: python, json, inheritance, while-loop, subclass

I imported a json file and created a while loop for rice bank account for super rice. I create def under parent code but encountered an error: TypeError: withdraw_money() missing 1 required positional argument: 'amount'. I am also trying to put new values for new week per each subclass that will append 500 for Super Rice Account and Prepaid, 0 for Normal Rice A. I am stuck with SuperRiceAccount.withdraw_money(amount) because of the error and I still need to figure out the function for the new week. Can anyone help me?

Here'a my code below

```
class BaseAccount:
      def __init__(self, account_id, account_type, full_name, birthday, balance,amount=500):
        self.account_id = account_id
        self.account_type = account_type
        self.full_name = full_name
        self.birthday = birthday
        self.balance = balance
        self.amount = amount

    def account_info(self):
        for p in data ['accounts']:
            print('You have successfully withdrawn 500 grams from the account.')
            print('Account ID:' + p['account_id'])
            print('Account Type:' + p['account_type'])
            print('Full Name:' + p['full_name'])
            print('Birthday:' + p['birthday'])
        print('Balance: ' + self.balance + ' left')

    def withdraw_money(self, amount):
        self.balance = self.balance - amount(500)
        for p in data['accounts']:
            print('You have successfully withdrawn 500 grams from the account.')
            print('Account ID:' + p['account_id'])
            print('Account Type:' + p['account_type'])
            print('Full Name:' + p['full_name'])
            print('Birthday:' + p['birthday'])
            print('Balance: ' + self.balance + ' left')

    def new_week(self):
        return

class SuperRiceAccount(BaseAccount):
    def __init__(self, account_id, account_type, full_name, birthday, balance):
        super().__init__(account_id, account_type, full_name, birthday, balance)
        if self.balance >= 2000:
            print ('You still have ', self.balance, ' left.')
        else:
            print('You do not have enough balance.')

    def new_week(self):
        if initial_balance < 2000:
            self.balance = self.balance + 500
            print('Your new balance is ', self.balance, ' left')

while True:
    print('( 1 ) List All Accounts')
    print('( 2 ) Withdraw Rice from an Account')
    print('( 3 ) New Week')
    print('( 4 ) Exit')
    print('')
   option = int(input('Enter your choice: '))
    if option == 1:
      for p in data['accounts']:
          print('Account ID:'+ p['account_id'])
          print('Account Type:' + p['account_type'])
          print('Full Name:' + p['full_name'])
          print('Birthday:' + p['birthday'])
          print('Balance:'+ str(p["balance"]))
          print('')

    if option == 2:
        print('')
        i = input('Enter Account ID:')
        print('')
        for p in data['accounts']:
            if p ['account_id'] == i:
                print('Account ID:' + p['account_id'])
                print('Account Type:' + p['account_type'])
                print('Full Name:' + p['full_name'])
                print('Birthday:' + p['birthday'])
                print('Balance: ' + str(p["balance"]) + ' left')
                print('')
            else:
                amount = input('Input 500 to withdraw 500 grams from this account:')
                SuperRiceAccount.withdraw_money(amount)
                SuperRiceAccount.account_info(amount)
                for p in data['accounts']:
                    print('Account ID:' + p['account_id'])
                    print('Account Type:' + p['account_type'])
                    print('Full Name:' + p['full_name'])
                    print('Birthday:' + p['birthday'])
                    print('Balance:' + str(p["balance"]))
                    print('')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `SuperRiceAccount` object when calling the method `withdraw_money`. 
What happens is that when you call that function the amount is passed as the first argument `self` and therefore the second argument `amount` is missing. 


Fix it by initializing:

```
bank = SuperRiceAccount([PASS HERE INITIALIZATION PARAMETERS])
```

and calling with:

```
bank.withdraw_money(amount)
bank.account_info(amount)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry isn't this one? SuperRiceAccount.withdraw_money(amount)

Comment: I tried what you suggested, I encountered an error: TypeError: __init__() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'account_id', 'account_type', 'full_name', 'birthday', and 'balance'. Sorry for too much questions on my end, programming is not really forte.

Comment: You should pass initialization parameters to create a bank account. There are many bugs in the code above - so it still won't fix them all (code is not very clear). However, the explanation for what you asked regarding missing ```amount``` parameter is answered above.

Comment: @maria Welcome! mark answer as solved if it solved the problem.